# How do I add this required field to the form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make this Form. It is not allowed to move to the next steps unless the person fills in the required fields. But I can't activate the "required" feature, even though I added it in HTML.
Therefore, I want you to help me and add or activate a required feature to Exact field in that form.
But I don't want all the fields, I just want them when I put the word required. And when I add new fields, I want them to work as well.
I also want to increase the width of the form to 90% of the total area, while also increasing the size of the progress bar.

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web);

/*basic reset*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #000, #fff); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
}

body {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: transparent;
}

/*headings*/
.fe-title-main {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #72bd43;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.fe-title {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #72bd43;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.fe-title-tabs {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #72bd43;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.fe-subtitle-main {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.06;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #232323;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 33px;
}

.fe-subtitle {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.06;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #232323;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.fe-mission {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #65655a;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.fe-setttings {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #232323;
    text-align: left;
    height: 34px;
}
hr {
  margin-top: 117px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

input, select, textarea {
    color: #40ae00;
}

/*Images*/
.rocket-img {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/*form styles*/
#msform {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}

/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    height: 55px;
}

#msform input:focus, #msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #70BD44;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    background: #72bd43;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px;
    margin: 20px 0px 16px 0px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 147px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: solid 1px #72bd43;
  
}

.begin-verificaiton {
   width: 147px;
    background: #72bd43;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;

}

#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #70BD44;
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    background: #fff;
    color: #232323;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px;
    margin: 20px 40px 16px 0px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 147px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: solid 1px #72bd43;
}
#msform .action-button-previous:hover, #msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #70BD44;
}

/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    border: solid 1px #cdcccb;
}

/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #cdcccb;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none;
}

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #70BD44;
    color: #fff;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #40ae00;
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-control-placeholder,
.form-control:valid + .form-control-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Tabs */
.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #40ae00;
    border: solid 1px #65655a;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #65655a;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #65655a;
    width: 190px;
    height: 43px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #65655a;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #40ae00;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #65655a;
}
```

```html
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
 
 <!-- MultiStep Form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <!-- start of form --> 
        <form id="msform">
            <!-- start of progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">ACCOUNT<br> INFORMATION</li>
                <li>IDENTITY<br> VERIFICATION </li>
                <li>ADDRESS<br> VERIFICATION </li>
                <li>ACCOUNT<br> ACTIVATION </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end of progressbar --> 
            
            <!-- start of fieldset -->
            <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <div class="text-center">
                <img class="rocket-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120" alt="" title="">
              </div>
                <h2 class="fe-title-main">Get started with your account!</h2>
                <h3 class="fe-subtitle-main">Thank you for regestering with us.</h3>
                <p  class="fe-mission">Before you are ready to go, we need some additional information from you, in compliance with KYC/AML regulations. <br>
                You need to provide further information about yourself and verify your identity. This wizard will guide you step-by-step. Please note that you will have to provide certain documents such as a passport, driver’s license and proof of address.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- start of footer --> 
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
              </div>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button begin-verification" value="BEGIN VERIFICATION"/>
                <!-- end of footer -->
            </fieldset>
            <!-- end of fieldset -->

            <!-- start of fieldset -->
            <fieldset>
              <!-- start of row -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="fe-title">Account Security & Settings</h2>
                <h3 class="fe-subtitle">Please select a security question and specify your personal answer!</h3>
                <p  class="fe-mission">This will help us verify your identity and allow you to log in securely to the Client Cabinet if you lose access for any reason.</p>
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" required id="" name="" class="form-control">
                    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="">Security Question</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="" name="" class="form-control" required>
                    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="">Your personal answer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <!-- end of row -->

             <!-- start of row -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                 <h3 class="fe-subtitle">Please select the industry you’re working in and your employment status.</h3>
                 <p class="fe-mission">By KYC (customer confirmation) and anti-money laundering (AML) terms, it is mandatory to check you current occupation and employment form.</p>
               </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" id="" name="" class="form-control" required>
                      <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="">Employment industry</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input  type="text" id="" name="" class="form-control" required>
                    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="">Employment status</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end of row -->

              <!-- start of row --> 

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3 class="fe-subtitle">Please provide some information about your future investment plans.</h3>
                  <p class="fe-mission">This information might be used to set individiual limits for your future investment.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="fe-setttings">How much do you estimate your investment with Titan FX will be during the next 12 months?</p>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="" name="" class="form-control" required>
                  <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="" >$1k-$5k USD</label>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="fe-setttings">For how long will you maintain your investment with&#x2028;Titan FX?</p>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="" name="" class="form-control" required>
                  <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="">1-3 months</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <!-- end of row --> 

              <!-- start of footer -->
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
              </div>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Back"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
                <!-- end of footer --> 
              </fieldset>
            <!-- end of fieldset --> 

            <!-- start of fieldset --> 
             <fieldset>
              <p>test</p>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#drivers">Drivers Licence</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#national">National ID</a></li>
                </ul>

              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="drivers" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                  <h2 class="fe-title-tabs">Enter information</h2>
                  <h3 class="fe-subtitle">Please provide information about your driver’s license.</h3>
                  <p class="fe-mission">Please make sure that all information is provided the way it is written on your document. Verify that the spelling matches exactly.</p>
                </div>
                  <div id="national" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>National ID</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                </div>
              </div>

               <!-- start of footer --> 
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
               </div>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Back"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
                <!-- end of footer --> 
            </fieldset>
            <!-- end of fieldset --> 

            <!-- start of fieldset --> 
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fe-title">Step Four</h2>
                <h3 class="fe-subtitle">Add Content Here</h3>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="Occupation Industry"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="Employment Status"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="What is your favorite book?"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                 <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="Security Answer"/>
               </div>

               <!-- start of footer --> 
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
              </div>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Back"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
                <!-- end of footer --> 
            </fieldset>
            <!-- end of fieldset --> 
        </form>
        <!-- end of form --> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.MultiStep Form -->

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `required="true"` to those inputs?

Comment: yes i did , nothing changed. really i am crazy . i think it needs some JavaScript codes but i am not the one who can handle this. i hope someone help me ,

Comment: I believe your jQuery is overriding the `required` attribute and changing to the next page no matter what

Comment: @Jeff Berlin
Can you fix the codes? Or you can even add the necessary codes. I will be very thankful to you. Because I really couldn't do anything and all my attempts failed